# Calculate sum of columns matching 2 criteria within a for loop

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Looking to calculate the sum of models objects macthing 2 requirements.

As an example this is what the table would look like

| User | Venue | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User_1 | Venue_A | 50 |
| User_1 | Venue_B | 25 |
| User_2 | Venue_A | 1 |
| User_1 | Venue_A | 50 |
| User_2 | Venue_A | 1 |
| User_1 | Venue_C | 25 |

In this example, I would like to use a `for loop` to sum the points allocated  against for each venue against User_1.

| User | Venue | Total Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User_1 | Venue_A | 100 |
| User_1 | Venue_B | 25 |
| User_1 | Venue_C | 25 |

I am struggling to understand how I can express the need for a double check within the loop

1. Step 1: check 1 - look up for `user.request`
2. Step 2:check 2 - look up for venue_x
3. Step 3: add points;
4. Step 4: ...restart process for next venue

There are 2 problems with my current function:

1. It calculates the sum of all points independently of the venue
2. It's outside of the queryset used in the `for loop` and therefore cannot return the number sum specific to the `venue` (*assuming I could get the first point working*)

**models.py**

```
class Itemised_Loyatly_Card(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    add_points = models.IntegerField(name = 'add_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)
```

**views**

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def user_loyalty_card(request):
    itemised_loyalty_cards = Itemised_Loyatly_Card.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
    sum_objects = Itemised_Loyatly_Card.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).aggregate(Sum("add_points")) # considering the loop will be with itemised_loyalty_cards , should the sum be in the same queryset?
   
    return render(request,"main/account/user_loyalty_card.html", {'itemised_loyalty_cards':itemised_loyalty_cards,'sum_objects':sum_objects})
```

**template**

```
{%for itemised_loyatly_card in itemised_loyalty_cards %}

{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue}}
{{itemised_loyatly_card.sum_objects}}</td> #**<-- this is obviously not working**

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a partial answer to my own question.

I needed to use a combination of `.values()` (*this identifies the column where the conditions, in my case venue*) are and `.annotate()` (*this identifies the column(s) I need to sum up that match the conditions*)

**views** (cant get the formatting right on stack)

```
def function(request):
queryset = model.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).values('venue').annotate(add_points=Sum('add_points')).annotate(use_points=Sum('use_points')).annotate(total=F('add_points')-F('use_points'))
return render(request,"main/account/user_loyalty_card.html", {'itemised_loyalty_cards':itemised_loyalty_cards})
```

**template**

```
{%for modelname in queryset %}
{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue}}
{{itemised_loyatly_card.total}}
{%endfor%}
```

Partial answer only, as it creates a problem - the foorlop now returns the venue ID and not the name for some reason.